# Why I can't find element by xpath?

Tags: angular, selenium, xpath

I have element:

`<span ng-click="openOrderAddPopup()" class="active g-button-style g-text-button g-padding-5px g-margin-right-10px ng-binding"> <i class="fa fa-plus g-margin-right-5px"></i>                                                                         "Add "</span>`

I want to find it by xpath.

This one works:
`*//span[@class='active g-button-style g-text-button g-padding-5px g-margin-right-10px ng-binding']`
but looks ugly and it's not unique because there are three such elements.

I want to find it by text but this both ways doesn't work:

`*//span[text()='\"Add \"']`

or

`*//span[contains(text(),'Add')]`

Comment: `*//span[contains(., 'Add')]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see `double quotes` like this `"Add"` in `HTML DOM.` Then it not a plain text that you can use it with `text()` method of `xpath`.

It is a `text node.` which you can defined in xpath v1.0 which Selenium usage.

I would advise you to try this xpath:

```
//span[@ng-click='openOrderAddPopup()' and contains(@class,'active')]
```

if this is not unique and have multiple entry then least preferable choice is xpath indexing.

```
(//span[@ng-click='openOrderAddPopup()' and contains(@class,'active')])[1]
```

to select the first element, `[2]` to select the second element and so on...